# direct javascript/css requests to same server as page in load balanced environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, load-balancing

I have a .net web application in a load balanced environment over 3 servers. The load balancing is done with a load balancer. My site is http://www.website.com with several JavaScript files such as http://www.website.com/script1.js, http://www.website.com/script2.js etc.

Is it possible to set it up that when request goes to server1 for http://www.website.com, then all javascript, css requests also go to server1, server2 or server3? Is there any web.config configuration that can be put in place to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load balancer should handle this itself. Generally, it will keep a user with the server they were initially balanced to. I'm not aware of any setting that controls this, though.

And this question might be better suited for serverfault.com.